# Store Rails 3 engine in different Github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I plan to hire a contractor to work on some modules for my Rails 3 app, *without exposing the entire app* to him.

I got an advise from SO that I should create an engine, mount it to my main app and let the contractor work on this engine.

How should I go about storing the engine in a different github repository? How do I tell my live (Heroku) server to load this engine from this repository, and how can my contractor make requests from my main app without accessing to the code?

Thank you.

Comment: you can add the code from the outside contractor as a git submodule but I cannot see how you can actually share the data without exposing the app. Maybe you can create a dummy rails app which will provide the models / classes he need without the real business logic

Comment: Thanks bcd. The contractor won't need actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to load the engine as a submodule in your main application. Heroku supports this as noted [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules).

The git for this is fairly easy. Make sure that you are in the base directory of the Rails app and run these commands.

```
git submodule add enginerepoaddress desired_destination
git add .
git commit -m 'Add rails engine git commit message'
```

To update, it's simply

```
git submodule submodule_name git pull origin master
```

The git documentation for submodules is available [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.5.4/git-submodule.html)